# How to parse JSON object into a list of objects in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, elasticsearch, json.net

our organization recently changed its database from sqlserver to elasticsearch and I am about creating an application for that,
I could successfully create an index and populated that with some information but when I retrieve the information, it returns me the data I really want plus lots of metadata which I don't really need in this context, now my question is how to extract the exact data I need and how to store it in a list,
it is the response from the [image: when I press the search index the response will be like this which is a JSON object]server when I press the search index button

but I am interested in information that comes exactly after the second "hits" especially I want to extract "_id", "Firstname", "Lastname" and store it in a generic list of the type person which has the corresponding fields.
and it is the code in the code-behind file
[image: code that is written in the code-behind file]

Comment: It's much easier to respond if you share the raw JSON in your question.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and JSON as **text**, rather than as a screen shot?  On stackoverflow we ask that questions include textual data such as code, error messages, exception details and data (JSON, XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: You can use https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy an example JSON response to your clipboard and generate some Json classes either by:

a. In Visual Studio select Edit / Paste Special / Paste JSON As Classes

b. If your data is not sensitive / you can clean it, use an online site such as http://json2csharp.com

Then deserialize from the Root object.

```
using var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
using var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);

var json = JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize<Rootobject>(jsonReader);
```

Then take the bit you need.

```
var response = json.hits.hits;
```

You can further optimise the process by scrubbing all properties on the outer objects that you don't want to deserialize into.

Comment: Thank you so much it is really the answer.
Thank you stackowerflow.com